# Sorting Array Dates in Order C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have some code that outputs data from each array, but I was just wondering for my twoData array is there a way so that the user can see the dates in either ascending or descending order. At the moment it outputs like:

16/03/2015
13/02/2015
12/02/2015
03/02/2015
02/02/2015
30/01/2015
29/01/2014
28/01/2014
27/01/2014
26/01/2013
23/01/2013
22/01/2013

Thanks.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //int ctr = 0; 

        string[] oneData = File.ReadAllLines("One.txt");
        string[] twoData = File.ReadAllLines("Two.txt");

         Console.WriteLine("Which array would you like to view?");
         string input = Console.ReadLine(); 

            Console.Write("\n");

          if (input.ToLower() == "one")
             Console.Write(string.Join("\n", oneData));

          else if(input.ToLower() == "two")
             Console.Write(string.Join("\n", twoData));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sort the strings in date order you would parse the values to dates:

```
dateData = dateData
  .OrderBy(d => DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
  .ToArray();
```

Use `OrderByDescending` for the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

```
 internal class HiringDate :IComparable
{
    public int day { get; set; }
    public int month { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }

  



    public HiringDate(int day=1, int month=1, int year=2000)
    {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{day}-{month}-{year}";
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        HiringDate hD = obj as HiringDate;
        if (year.CompareTo(hD.year) == 0)
        {
            if (month.CompareTo(hD.month) == 0)
            {
               return day.CompareTo(hD.day);    

            }
            else return month.CompareTo(hD.month);


        }
        else return year.CompareTo(hD.year);
    }
}
```